# How to access Sinatra port using Docker with docker-compose run

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, sinatra

I'm not sure how to a correctly expose the Sinatra port `4567` from Docker back to the host. Running the app locally has no issues.

The following repository show cases the issue https://gitlab.com/davidhooey/sinatra-docker

From searching I noticed the following issue [Running Ruby Sinatra inside a Docker container not able to connect (via Mac host) or find commands (in different scenario)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027248/running-ruby-sinatra-inside-a-docker-container-not-able-to-connect-via-mac-host) where the `--host 0.0.0.0` is passed into the `rackup` command. However, I'm launching the site programmatically through using `Site.run!`.

File tree

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
├── app.rb
├── docker-compose.yml
├── site.rb
└── views
    └── index.erb
```

`app.rb`

```
module App
    class App
        def initialize(args)
            # Do some stuff before launching site.
            # Launch site
            Site.run!
        end
    end
end

App::App.new(ARGV)
```

In `site.rb` the `:bind` Sinatra setting is set to `0.0.0.0`.

`site.rb`

```
require 'sinatra'

module App
    class Site < Sinatra::Base
        set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
        set :static, true
        set :public_dir, File.expand_path(__dir__)

        get '/' do
            erb :'/index'
        end
    end
end
```

Even still the site is inaccessible when run within a Docker container.

`Dockfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.2.6

EXPOSE 4567

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN gem install bundler && bundle install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    app:
        build: .
        hostname: app
        ports:
            - "4567:4567"
        environment:
            - RUBYOPT=-W0 -KU -E utf-8:utf-8
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: .
              target: /app
```

Local works:

```
ruby app.rb
```

Docker not so much:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run --rm app ruby app.rb
```

Docker run example.

```
$ docker-compose run --rm app ruby app.rb
[2018-07-27 14:21:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2018-07-27 14:21:10] INFO  ruby 2.2.6 (2016-11-15) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v2.0.3) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2018-07-27 14:21:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4567
```

Launch a bash shell into the running container to access Sinatra within the container.

```
$ docker exec -it aa8f64b009b0 bash
root@app:/app# curl localhost:4567
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sinatra Docker</title>
    </head>
   <body>
        <h1>Sinatra Docker</h1>
   </body>
</html>
root@app:/app#
```

Any ideas are more than welcome on how to access the Sinatra port running within the container from the localhost when Sinatra is launched programmatically.

Comment: Did you log into the docker image to check that your app is running properly and bound to an interface?

Comment: I have added the Docker Run, showing the startup of Sinatra within the container. Seems like it is starting on the port without issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When running an app with `docker-compose run`, service ports will **not be mapped**. This is by design, because `run` is meant for one-off tasks and not for booting the whole compose stack.

See documentation here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

> The second difference is that the docker-compose run command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports.

To map the ports you either need to use `run` with `--service-ports`, or add a `command` section to your `docker-compose.yml` and then use `docker-compose up`:

**Option 1** (using run):

```
docker-compose run --service-ports --rm app ruby app.rb -o 0.0.0.0
```

**Option 2** (booting the whole stack):

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    hostname: app
    command: ruby app.rb -o 0.0.0.0  # <-- Add this
    ports:
      - "4567:4567"
    ...
```

And then:

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: I also found it necessary to bind Sinatra to an arbitrary host using `command: ruby app.rb -o 0.0.0.0` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41673831/18706 - confusing as no such docker-compose config is required for Rails). After that, it was possible to connect from host to http://localhost:4567